# At wits end trying to make .exe

Tags: python

Python 3.65, windows 7.
I am at my wits end. I've spent the last 2 weeks learning python from scratch. I just want to make small system utils and I finally made a little program and it simply will not run as a stand alone .exe file.

I have spent the last 2 days trying every suggestion I can find and nothing works. For me there is no point in investing all this time and hassle if I can't make executables.

What I am asking is can some kind person try to compile this on their windows machine and see if it's just me (or my computer Windows 7 64bit) that is the problem. I have read somewhere there are problems with win 7 with some exes.

If that's not possible could someone look at the code and see if there is anything obvious that might cause compile problems?

I have tried cx_freeze and pyinstaller. they make the exes. They run, show a dos box and then nothing.

I have even tried down-grading as far as python 2.7 and I am just in a right mess I don't know what else to do. I have really enjoyed learning Python and I have to get this sorted before continuing and it's driving me crazy, please help.

Steve.

```
import pyperclip
from tkinter import *
from ctypes import windll
import os
import time
#default folder for saves "c:\\cb-pastes"
#default txt file "c:\\cb-pastes\\saved.txt"
#================set up gui=======================
root = Tk()

#check if "c:\\cb-pastes" exists, if not, create folder
check_folder=os.path.isdir("c:\\cb-pastes")
if not check_folder:
    os.makedirs("c:\\cb-pastes")

#button functions
def call_save():
    ct=time.asctime()          #get system time and date in ct
    cb_txt = pyperclip.paste() #store clipboard in cb_txt

    f = open("c:\\cb-pastes\\saved.txt","a") # open the file:
    f.write ("\n")                           #newline
    f.write (ct)                             #save date and time
    f.write ("\n")
    f.write (cb_txt)                         #append to text file      
    f.write ("\n")
    f.write ("-----------------------------")  
    f.close()                               #Close the file

def call_clear(): #clear clipboard
    if windll.user32.OpenClipboard(None):
        windll.user32.EmptyClipboard()
        windll.user32.CloseClipboard()


def call_view(): #open text file of saved clips
    os.startfile('c:\\cb-pastes\\saved.txt')

def call_viewcb(): #open text file of current clipboard contents
    cb_get = pyperclip.paste()
    f = open("c:\\cb-pastes\\temp.txt","w")
    f.write (cb_get)
    f.close()
    os.startfile('c:\\cb-pastes\\temp.txt')


#create window
root.title ("CBMan V0.7")
root.geometry ("230x132")

# create buttons
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

button1 = Button(app, text = "Save Clipboard", command=call_save)
button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
button2 = Button(app, text = "Clear Clipboard", command=call_clear)
button2.grid()
button3 = Button(app, text = "View Saves     ", command=call_view)
button3.grid()
button4 = Button(app, text = "View Clipboard ", command=call_viewcb)
button4.grid()

#insert logo
photo = PhotoImage(file="c:\\cb-pastes\\cbman.gif")
label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

Comment: You never call Tkinter's `mainloop()`, so the expected behavior of this program is to exit immediately.  You need to make your code work when run from Python normally before even thinking about making an .exe from it.

Comment: good grief I can't belive it, IT WORKS. I was led to believe you didn't need mainloop() with Python 3, I am soo happy thank you so much.

Comment: for some reason I cant mark your reply as answered.

Comment: That's because it's written as just a *comment*. @jasonharper needs to write an actual answer.

Comment: Ah I see,  OK thanks Tom.

Comment: Now my antivirus says my compiled code is a virus and keeps deleting it haha, will this ever end? I have now white-listed my program, but it worries me that 11 other virus checkers ou tof 60 also think its a virus. Is this normal? Or is there something in my source code that looks "virusy" to heuristics when compiled?